# Are newspaper articles more liberal than their readership?

Tags: price-theory

This question was posted on a forum (see [here](http://www.econjobrumors.com/topic/question-on-todays-murphy-price-theory-final-uofc)), and I thought it was interesting, especially in light of the recent spotlight on Matthew Gentzkow's work. So, I'm re-posting it here.

> Some studies claim that newspaper articles are usually more liberal than their readership. Since the news market is competitive, should we doubt this claim?

Comment: How is this posting related to the field of economics?

Comment: If it were significantly improved, this might be a suitable question for [skeptics.se]. But you'd need to specify which set of newspaper articles, which country, what time period, what definition of "liberal".

Comment: @Mico  It's clearly a question about trying to sort out the incentives and the various supply and demand forces in the newspaper industry. Also, as the link notes, it is a HW question straight out of a PhD level microeconomics course.

Answer (score 4):

This strikes me as a straightforward industrial organization anomaly question. Like, why do hot dogs and buns come in different counts to a package or why are the finest apples shipped out of apple producing regions?

[Gentzkow and Shapiro (2010)](http://faculty.chicagobooth.edu/matthew.gentzkow/research/biasmeas.pdf) that this paradox is only an apparent contradiction. They find slant is mostly a product of readership bias.

> By contrast, we find much less evidence for a role of newspaper owners
>   in determining slant. While slant is somewhat correlated across
>   co-owned papers, this effect is driven by the geographic clustering of
>   ownership groups. After controlling for the geographic location of
>   newspapers, we find no evidence that the variation in slant has an
>   owner-specific component. We also find no evidence that pressure from 
>   incumbent politicians or the tastes of reporters are important drivers
>   of slant.

But jmbejara already mentions knowing about Gentzkow so it isn't obvious what he's looking for beyond this insight.

Timothy Taylor,  Managing Editor of the JEP and blogger at CONVERSABLE ECONOMIST also has an article on this subject that may be of interest, 
[The Economics of Media Bias](http://conversableeconomist.blogspot.com/2015/03/the-economics-of-media-bias.html).